# What is the best way to get in contact with a Lego expert?

Tags: set-identification

Catawiki is looking to hire a Lego expert to estimate the value of offered sets and arrange its weekly [Lego auction](http://auction.catawiki.com/lego-veiling). Where and how could we find people who might be interested in such a position?

Comment: Are you planning to commission a builder to create something, buy it from them and auction it off? Sorry, but I haven't yet heard of Catawiki or its Lego auction. Is it some kind of a special event?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Catawiki is an auction website with over 100 auction categories, one of them being Lego. Users can offer up their lots for auction but these will have to be approved by the Auctioneer. This expert will identify the set, determine whether it meets the minimum requirements for the auction (estimated value, completeness, description, pictures etc) and arrange an attractive list of lots every week. I understand the word "build" in my question is rather ambiguous in a Lego setting. I will edit it immediately.

Comment: Ok, this makes the question pretty clear, thank you for your edit :)

Comment: Does the auctioneer needs to be local? Where is this position open?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a recruiting ad

Comment: At the moment Catawiki only requires the expert to live within the European Union (preferably in NL, BE, FR, DE, IT, SP or UK ). The job is done from home and at flexible hours.

Answer (score 2):

An effective way of contacting LEGO hobbyist is either by..

- Contacting Local LEGO User Groups or similar hobbyist associations

Many countries and areas have their local associations. For a map of regional associations, see [LEGO Ambassador Network's LUG map](https://lan.lego.com/lugs). By contacting representatives of association, you can easily contact local help.

- Requesting help from online LEGO forums

Another option is to post a message at online LEGO forums. There are many forums as some are theme-specific and some are area- or language-specific and thus it is hard to pinpoint exactly which forum one should try; it depends on the case. Safe bet would be to post in few of the global online forums, such as [Eurobricks](http://www.eurobricks.com).

- Contacting individual hobbyist via site/blog/email

If one wishes to contact particular hobbyist, a good way is see if that particular hobbyist has own blog or similar page. Even gallery services such as Flickr often contain email which can be used to contact the hobbyist.

For this particular case, I would advice posting a message at Eurobricks since it has particularly large amount of readers.